# How to create an additional terminal-based output stream?

Tags: c, unix, terminal, file-descriptor

**How would I create an additional file descriptor that connects to the terminal for debug messages?** I'd like something just like standard out/error streams (`stdout`/`stderr`). For clarity sake, I'll call this new stream `spdbg` (for *"special debug"*). I thought about using `dup()` to duplicate the `stdout`/`stderr` stream, but if that stream gets redirected to a file then that means `spdbg` also gets redirected to the same file, which I don't want. Instead, I'd like `spdbg` to redirect to the terminal, just like `stdout`/`stderr` initially do. In other words, if `stdout`/`stderr` gets redirected to a file, then `spdbg` should still point to the terminal. However, `spdbg` can still be redirected to a file, if the user wishes to do so.

Comment: You could consider opening `/dev/tty`?